# menu with characters in c and accents

Tags: c, menu

My C code uses special characters to create menu borders, and also uses the locale.h library for the program to accept accents, however with the library and accents, the menu border characters change, is it possible to have both?

I tried to find another library for accents but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: UTF-8 or something else?

Comment: Please also tell us what OS you are using.  OS makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do something like this so that it doesn't change:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

    // Code that needs to handle accents here.

    // Go back to default for menu borders.
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");

    // Then you display the menu borders.

    return 0;
}
```